# How can I modify the value and font of a text class in fabric.js dynamically?

Tags: fabricjs

I am working with fabric.js and I have used a fabric.Text class like this:

```
var text = new fabric.Text('hello world', {
    fontSize: 30,
    left:190,
});
var circle = new fabric.Circle({
    radius: 100,
    fill: '#eef',
    scaleY: 0.5
});
var group = new fabric.Group([ text, circle ], {
    left: 150,
    top: 100,
    angle: -10
});

canvas.add(rect1, rect2, rect3, circle, triangle,group);
canvas.on({
    'object:moving': onChange,
    'object:scaling': onChange,
    'object:rotating': onChange,
});

function onChange(options) {
    options.target.setCoords();
    canvas.forEachObject(function(obj) {
        if (obj === options.target)
            return;
        obj.setOpacity(options.target.intersectsWithObject(obj) ? 0.5 : 1);
    });
}
```

The main problem is that I can not modify the value of the text of the text class dynamically. How I can modify it?

Answer (score 1):

Try with `text.set({ text: 'New Text' });`

Regards.